# Intercept or Decorate calls to ILogger

Tags: c#, logging, castle, interception

I'm currently using castle windsor, along with it's logging facility in my application.

However, in my logging I would like to include some contextual information that is not within the logged message, but stored within the [`CallContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext(v=vs.110).aspx).

I have tried to do this by intercepting the calls to `ILogger` using the following:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseNLog());
        container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new LoggerResolver(container.Kernel));

        var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
    }
}

public class LoggerResolver: ISubDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;
    private static ProxyGenerator _proxyGenerator;

    static LoggerResolver()
    {
        _proxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();
    }

    public LoggerResolver(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public bool CanResolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return dependency.TargetType == typeof(ILogger);
    }

    public object Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return _proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(_kernel.Resolve<ILogger>(), new LoggingInterceptor());
    }
}

public class LoggingInterceptor: IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        //Some modification to message here
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

But the variable `logger` is of type `NLog.Loggger` rather than the dynamic proxy I was expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some digging with ILSpy seems to show that you won't be able to intercept calls to the `ILogger` instantiation. The `ILogger` intance is created directly by the `NLogFactory` (same thing for all logging factories I looked into, log4net, console, etc)

```
// Castle.Services.Logging.NLogIntegration.NLogFactory
public override ILogger Create(string name)
{
    Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger(name);
    return new NLogLogger(logger, this);
}
```

If this is really necessary you should be able to inherit the factories you're interested into (basically, `NLogFactory` and `ExtendedNLogFactory`) in order to override the `ILogger` creation. Then create a instance-based proxy of the ILogger and plug in your custom interceptors. Finally inform the `LoggingFacility` that you want to use a custom factory.

I started being pessimist about your problem but I found the solution to be quite simple to implement, so you shouldn't have too many problems to achieve what you want.
Code? Of course :)

```
public class MyFactory : NLogFactory
{
    public override ILogger Create(string name)
    {
        var il = base.Create(name);
        var pg =  new ProxyGenerator();
        return pg.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget<ILogger>(il, new LoggingInterceptor());
    }
}

public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        //Some modification to message here
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseNLog().LogUsing<MyFactory>());

        var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
        logger.Debug("data"); // we intercept this call, success
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I ended up solving it in a very similar way (I newed up an `NLogFactory` instance in an implementation of `ILoggerFactory`) - but I prefer your method.