# How to hook interceptor for ILogger

Tags: castle-windsor

I'm using the LoggingFacility, and need to add interceptor for the ILogger instances, created by the facility.

So far I tried to modify the component model for ILogger, and this didn't work, as the loggers are not really resolved using the standard resolving mechanism (they are created by a factory, which use some wrappers).

I was thinking to override the logging subresolver, but kernel.Resolver does not allow replacing (or wrapping) the resolver added by the facility.

I was thinking about hooking to Kernel.DependencyResolving, but it appears I can not replace the dependency there.

What is the most appropriate place to put such a hook, so I can add Interceptor for the ILogger.

EDIT: After a lot of poking around, I came with somewhat "hackish" solution, which unfortunately depends on small reflection usage.

The real problem appears to be, that the way the loggers are constructed does not follow (for me) the castle spirit of doing things. I.e. the resolver does not use the already registered logger factory, so it's impossible to add interceptors to the factory itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790258/intercept-or-decorate-calls-to-ilogger

Answer (score 1):

There is a great article about that on CodeProject: [Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) in C# using Castle DynamicProxy](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1083684/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-AOP-in-Csharp-using-Ca) from [Linjith Kunnon](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=2544827). It shows you how to define a Interceptor

```
public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var methodName = invocation.Method.Name;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Entered Method:{0}, Arguments: {1}", methodName, string.Join(",", invocation.Arguments)));
            invocation.Proceed();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Sucessfully executed method:{0}", methodName));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Method:{0}, Exception:{1}", methodName, e.Message));
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exiting Method:{0}", methodName));
        }
    }
}
```

And how to register it with Castle.Windsor

```
kernel.Register(
    Component.For<LoggingInterceptor>()
        .ImplementedBy<LoggingInterceptor>()
    );

kernel.Register(
    Component.For<IRocket>()
        .ImplementedBy<Rocket>()
        .Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<LoggingInterceptor>()).Anywhere
    );
```

Please note that there is more valuable content in the linked article and that the whole code provided here is from the article and not from me. All kudos goes to Linjith Kunnon.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not asnwer the question. I know how to add interceptors, but I was asking specifically about LoggingFacility, which does not actually register ILogger in the container, but uses own resolver.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own logger factory (derived from default implementation matching your logging framework) and then you can setup facility to use this factory like this:

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net().LogUsing<MyFactory>());
```

See full example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790258/intercept-or-decorate-calls-to-ilogger)

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem with one specific implementation. I'm after a more generic approach - to work both for log4net and nlog.

Comment: @SunnyMilenov Well the question was about how to hook an interceptor to ILogger. Using custom logger factory is the way. How exactly is the factory implemented is another story. You can of course leave `UseLog4Net` call completely, use just `LogUsing<>()` and pass your own implementation of `ILoggerFactory` implemented as decorator around whatever concrete implementation you want...